# How to fix submit button with css parameters for internet explorer?

Tags: css

My site works fine with chrome nad firefox but appereantly it doesn't show submit button properly with Internet Explorer 11.

Can someone please check what is wrong

[image]

This is the style.css code for button:

```
#searchsubmit { 
 font-family: Frutiger, Lato;
 background: url('images/search.png');
 cursor: pointer;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 border: 0px;
 float:right; 
 margin-top:5px;
}

.searchform input, .searchform input#s, placeholder { 
 font-family: Frutiger, Lato;
 background: #4D6B87;
 height: 30px;
 border: 0px;
 color: #EAEAEA;
 font-size: 14px;
 padding-left: 5px; 
}
```

all style.css is available here: www.virmodrosti.com/wp-content/themes/virmodrosti/style.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Solution :**

I found a way but you'll have to use Internet Explorer's conditional comment, this will resolve your issue, do it like so :

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style>
    #searchsubmit {
         position:absolute;
         right:20px;
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

---

**Second solution :**

I am not sure about this one since I don't use internet explorer anymore so I couldn't test it, but maybe if you simply add :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

It will emulate as edge on Internet Explorer 11 only, but you'll have to try.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
.searchform#searchform input, .searchform#searchform button {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0;
}
.searchform#searchform input {
    width: calc( 100% - 40px );
    margin-right: -2px;
}
.searchform#searchform button {
    width: 30px;
    margin-left: -2px;
}
```

Comment: Is this happening because of this entry * { padding: 0; margin: 0; } and maybe IE doesn't properly recognize that?